# Why IE7 iframes pops up in new window on page load

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-7, popup

I have a javascript that sets the iframe 'src' on page load. Every time the page refreshes or the iframe itself it creates multiple pop-ups of that iframe.

Here is an example of how I set the URL to the iFrame: 
iframe ID is 'stage'

document.getElementById('stage').src = 'xyz.html';

Please, any thoughts on that.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the src attribute to a wrong value, some browsers get problems with later (correct) values. Some of them get also problems if you display a local file (file://...) and later a global one (http://...) in the same iframe.

If you like to get more personalized help, you should post some more lines of your code.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and thanks. The reason I had posted this was because I've been working with Disqus which is a commenting platform and when I loaded their platform within an iFrame it was causing multiple pop-ups on IE7. I thought I was coding the iframe wrong but it was an issue with their platform. I think their working on a fix for it so no worries. Thanks.